# Polymer 1.0 app-theme only affecting index.html and not on custom elements

Tags: css, polymer

I'm using the Polymer Starter Kit, and I wanted to move the scaffold into it's own element `<main-scaffold>`. There are styles in `app-theme.html` that applied to it before I moved it into from index.html into it's own  element, but now none of the styles apply. This is the case for any set of elements I've put into my own custom elements. The custom styles applied to `<paper-material>` from `app-theme.html` are not applied inside my `<home-page>` element. I want certain elements to have themes applied to them globally. The only style inside `app-theme.html` that apply anywhere else are the CSS Custom Properties such as `--dark-primary-color`.

Is there any way I can create themes that apply to the entire project? I've tried specifically importing app-theme.html into my elements, and it doesn't make a difference. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The themes from [polymerthemes.com](https://polymerthemes.com/) should apply across your entire project.

Just download one of the pre-made themes (or create your own using the [Polymer Theme Builder](https://polymerthemes.com/custom-style/)) and link to it like this in your `<head>`:

```
<style is="custom-style">
    @import url("path/to/theme.css");
</style>
```

Alternatively, have a look to see how styles are applied on that site.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the creators of polymerthemes.com.

Comment: FYI, better [theme installation instructions](https://polymerthemes.com/help/) have now been added for all themes on polymerthemes.com. Have a read, they should give you a better understanding of the theming options for Polymer based projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the following worked for me. Inside your dom-module add:

```
<link rel="import" type="css" href="../styles/app-theme.css">
```

For example:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <link rel="import" type="css" href="../styles/app-theme.css">
  <template>
    <paper-button raised class="primary">Click Me!</paper-button>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

This seems to only be needed for certain paper elements though. The paper-checkbox works without it. Not an ideal solution though, to be sure.

Comment: Theme styles are provided by a html file (app-theme.html) in Polymer Starter Kit . Did you copy the contents and create app-theme.css ?

Comment: @Kenji no, I think they provided an alternative link for the css download, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that putting following in my custom element was causing the vulcanize task in gulpfile.js to crash (leaving the remaining tasks not run).

```
<link rel="import" href="/styles/app-theme.html">
```

Using relative path solved this problem

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../../styles/app-theme.html">
```

---

Worked somehow, but I think this is not the right thing to do. app-theme.html contains many css code that my custom element doesn't need.
Using mixins ( @apply(--mixin-name); )  looks like a good way, but hadn't tried it out yet. I think modification to app-theme.html would be necessary anyways.

I wish Polymer Starter Kit introduces a best practice for applying default margins/paddings/etc for paper-material/etc.

---

**Edit Jul 2**

Following didn't get applied.

app-theme.html

```
:root {
…
--app-paper-material-theme: {
   border-radius: 2px;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 16px 0 16px 0;
   width: calc(98.66% - 16px);
   margin: 16px auto;
   background: white;
 };
}
```

my-customelement-using-papermaterial.html

```
<style>
paper-material {
  @apply(--app-paper-material-theme);
}
</style>
```

---

My researching was messed up and posted wrong results in this few hours, so I decided to delete the portions. Sorry for those who saw them and took some kind of action.